# Replacing old values in dictionary with new values

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
d =
{1.0: 86, 2.0: 4406, 3.0: 523, 4.0: 324, 5.0: 1641, 6.0: 863}
```

I want to scale the values present in the dictionary to the range (0,255) and replace the scaled values with the old ones. To do this I use the `MinMaxScaler` from `sklearn`.
I do the following:

```
MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 255)).fit_transform(np.array(list(distance.values())).reshape(-1,1)).astype(int)
```

Now the results for the above line of code is:

```
array([[  0],
       [254],
       [ 25],
       [ 14],
       [ 91],
       [ 45]])
```

I want the values in dictionary to be replaced with the values (output) presented above that is with the scaled values present in the array. The desired output should look like:

```
d =
{1.0: 0, 2.0: 254, 3.0: 25, 4.0: 14, 5.0: 91, 6.0: 45}
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the new array is the same size as the dictionary, you could iterate through the dictionary and replace each element:

```
for index, (key, value) in enumerate(d.items()):
    d[key] = array[index]
```

Comment: I believe it d[key] = array[index]. However, the solution works fine! Thanks